# Keeping part of array constant

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of float values which I then pass to an equation to produce a corresponding array.  However, I would like to keep the first n values of this array constant, and then all values after that to be passed to the equation.

What is this best way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just slice the array to pass the values after the *nth* to your "equation" (which I assume is a function?).

```
def equation(l):
    return sum(l)    # for example

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
n = 4

>>> equation(a[n:])
26
>>> equation(a[3:6])
15
```

This passes only those values after the fourth in list `a`. Actually it passes a *copy* of that part of the list after the fourth, so your function is free to change the values therein without side effects.